# Select non-NaN data randomly from a pandas DF (both row and col have to be random)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building a recommender system, and have some ratings data here.
Each row represents a user, each column represents a product, and each datapoint represents the user's rating for a product.

```
in: np.array(df)

array([[ 0.,  5.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the above (I put it into a numpy array for easier viewing on stackoverflow).

For each row, I want to select 10% of the non-zero items, and set it to 0. However, I also want to capture the row and column number of each modified cell into a dictionary. (If I set a certain cell to 0, i want to keep a record of which cell i have changed to 0)

My current solution is to change all the zeroes to NaN first. Then, with this dataframe of NaNs, when I set a datapoint to 0, I am able to identify which cells I have modified.

```
in: np.array(df[df.iloc[:] !=0])

out: array([[ nan,   5.,   5.,  nan,  nan,   1.],
       [  5.,  nan,   4.,  nan,   1.,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  5.,  nan,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  4.,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   4.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   4.,   4.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   5.,   4.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   5.,  nan,   5.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   5.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   5.,  nan,  nan],
       [  5.,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan]])
```

However, I'm not sure how to randomly select 10% of non-NaN data from each row, and how to store the row index and column names of which cells i have modified. :

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether a vectorized approach is possible (since you are selecting a variable number of items from each row), but it's straightforward if you're willing to use a loop in Python (it should be pretty fast in Cython):

```
import random
import math
from itertools import groupby

nonzero_indices = list(zip(*np.where(data != 0)))
indices_to_drop = []
for _, g in groupby(nonzero_indices, lambda x:x[0]):
    li=list(g)
    indices_to_drop += random.sample(li,math.ceil(len(li)/10))
    # sample a tenth, rounded up, of each row's non-zero items
for idx in indices_to_drop:
    data[idx] = 0
```

Also, if you choose to do this, do it in NumPy and build the Pandas dataframe later, because indexing the underlying array through pandas is painfully slow.